# Download Mathematica 8 Trial

Tags: version-8, windows

My school uses mathematica 8 on several of their computers.

I would like to download a trail version for my home computer.

I would like the same version.  Is there a place I can download mathematica 8?

Comment: I very seriously doubt it.  Why not just download the V9 trial?  You'll have a few extra capabilities but not a lot of compatibility issues.

Comment: Well I was running mathematica 9 but the trail version just ended, so I figured I would get the the school has :D

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP is trying to learn ...

Comment: @belisarius  I agree.  What possible reason would there be for a down vote?

Comment: @MarkMcClure I'm not fond of "revenge (up/down)voting", but I upvoted the question because someone trying to get tools for learning shouldn't be mistreated like that.

Comment: @Robert, You might check with your school and see if their site license allows Home Licenses for their students. Also WRI has some significant discounts on academic versions of their software: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/how-to-buy/education/students.html.